# Index and Match to a file posted on SharePoint returning #Ref Error

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

I have two Excel files posted on SharePoint. With the master file, I've created INDEX, MATCH array formula, referencing the other file. I've entered the entire NUC, and the formula works fine while both files are open.

However, once the referenced report is closed, and Shift+Ctrl+Enter the cell, it returns #Ref! error. When I open the referenced report and do the same, it works fine.

Does anyone have any suggestions or recommendations for what I can do to fix it?

Comment: What have you researched or tried so far to resolve this? Can you share the link syntax?

Comment: I tried vlookup using NUC, it works fine. this issue only happens with index/match...

Comment: Here is the formula I am using NU is the file location. Again, the formula works fine as long as NUC\Filename.xlsx is open....
=INDEX('NUC\Filename.xlsx'!Table1[[A]:[Z]],MATCH(1,('NUC\Filename.xlsx'!Table1[ForecastMonth]=[@ForecastMonth])*('NUC\Filename.xlsx'!Table1[Name]=[@Name]),0),11)

Comment: When you use `NUC`, do you mean `UNC` for the address on the server?

Comment: sorry been playing too much with intel's new NUC:) I do mean UNC, and there is \\ before the address

Comment: Use the actual ranges instead of the table names when the workbooks are closed. Let us know if that works.

Answer (score 0):

According to this Microsoft Support document; [Create an external reference (link) to a cell range in another workbook](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/create-an-external-reference-link-to-a-cell-range-in-another-workbook-HP010342364.aspx) brackets need to be used around the file name when using external links to closed files (about half way down, 2nd external reference heading).

> When the source is not open in Excel, the external reference includes
>   the entire path.
>  External reference
>   *=SUM('C:\Reports[Budget.xlsx]Annual'!C10:C25)*

So, in your formula, the `Filename.xlsx` should be `[Filename.xlsx]`

Also, I'm not sure, but it looks like your UNC should start with a `\\` if there isn't a drive letter. But if it's working, don't fix it. :-)

Comment: Thanks, I've tried putting a square bracket, but when I do ctr-shft-enter, excel automatically removes square bracket, and will still return #Ref! error...

Answer (score 0):

Names only work when referencing internal items. As soon as you want to reference an external item, the item must be open for excel to reference it by name. Once the workbook is closed, you'll need to reference actual cell ranges rather than the named range.

Comment: That actually worked! However, I'm now getting out of resource error... Does INDEX/MATCH require that much resources?

Comment: Depends on your array size and resources available

Answer (score 0):

Seems like it's not possible to reference a Table Name in another workbook.
You have to reference a set range to avoid the #REF error.

e.g.
Won't work: =ReferenceWorkbook![TableName[Column]]
Will work: =ReferenceWorkbook!SheetName!$A$2:$A$15

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).